# Default options for the i18n translations gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a rails app the uses the standard i18n translations gem. It's a multi-tenant app and relies on parsing the current tenant from the subdomain.

```
en:
  foo:
    bar: "Welcome to %{subdomain}"
```

I have a few keys (e.g. `subdomain` above) that I'm using very often in my translations. In my view I have to keep passing in the same key in various places

```
t("foo.bar", subdomain: current_subdomain)
```

Is there a way I can specify a default set of keys (like `subdomain`) that are always passed to the translations by default so I don't have to type it out all the time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gem [route_translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) for some solutions.